# Plotting the relationship between all numerical variables

Tags: python, pandas

My task is to plot the relationship between all numerical variables.
The most obvious decision is

```
sns.pairplot(titset, diag_kind = 'kde', size=4)
```

But i get a hude and unreadable result - [RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNEBl.png)

which is loading for 40 seconds

Are there any methods to do it properly? Or i just misunderstood the task

Also i left my dataframe

[MY DATAFRAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grFhI.png)

Comment: you are asking for the pairwise relationships of 10 columns -- 10 choose 2 = 45. of course its gonna be pretty crowded. You can help us help you by specifying what is it exactly that you want.

Comment: How can i transfer only certain columns in this method?

Comment: Pass only the columns you want: `sns.pairplot(titset[['colA', 'colB']], diag_kind = 'kde', size=4)`